# Getting decoupled modules in NestJS

Tags: architecture, nestjs, decoupling

I can't seem to figure out how to use dependency injection in NestJS to my liking.

Here's my project structure:

```
App --- User ------ Common
  \ \-- Article --/
   \--- Chat
```

In words: One big app module being the app. Feature modules `user`, `article` and `chat`. Now if some feature wants to interact with other, it needs to depend on `common` module.

In my simple case that would be:
Article database has simple object about author. So once it retrieves article data, it wants to retrieve author (user's) data. But it must not see on `user` module.

My solution was to have `service` interfaces in common module.

```js
export interface UserCommonService {
    getUser(id: string): Promise<User | null>
}
```

Real `UserService` would implement this common service and through dependency injection I would get it in controller without being dependent on `user` module.

```js
@Injectable()
export class UserService implements UserCommonService {
  async getUser(id: string): Promise<User | null> {
    ...
  }
}
```

```js
@ApiTags("v1/article")
@Controller("v1/article")
export class ArticleController {
  constructor(
    private readonly articleService: ArticleService,
    @Inject('UserService') private readonly userService: UserCommonService
  ) { }

  @Get(":id")
  async getArticle(@Param("id") id: string): Promise<...> {
    const article = await this.articleService.getArticle(id)
    const user = await this.userService.getUser(article.author.id)

    return {author: user, article: article}
  }
}
```

Now I am lost at what to do in DI modules to make this work. To my best knowledge, I put following in `user.module.ts`

```js
@Module({
  imports: [TypegooseModule.forFeature([User])],
  controllers: [UserController],
  providers: [UserService, { provide: 'UserService', useClass: UserService }],
  exports: ['UserService']
})
```

But I have no idea what to put in `article.module` to import it. Or maybe to `app.module`? Everything I do results in error or is not possible - like imports cannot have string value.
Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things:

In your `user.module.ts`, you should only have `UserService` in the providers array once, and exported like so

```js
@Module({
  imports: [TypegooseModule.forFeature([User])],
  controllers: [UserController],
  providers: [{ provide: 'UserService', useClass: UserService }],
  exports: ['UserService']
})
export class UserModule {}
```

I would suggest changing the `'UserService'` string to a constant or a `symbol` to make it reusable without possibly spelling it wrong, but that's up to you.

Then in your `article.module.ts` to allow for `@Inject('UserService')` you just need to import the `UserModule` like so

```js
@Module({
  imports: [UserModule, TypegooseModule.forFeature([Article]),
  controller: [ArticleController],
  providers: [ArticleService]
})
export class ArticleModule {}
```

And Nest should not complain about any errors for that. Let me know if you face any problems

Comment: You are right, there are no errors and it works as expected :) However, I still have user dependency in article. Specifically, I imported user.module inside article.module. It is much better, but not quite what I had in mind, yet.

Comment: One option if you just don't want to reuse any modules in any other is to redeclare the TypegooseModule dependency for model: `User` and then make direct queries instead of going through the `UserService`, but with this approach you will most likely end up with duplicate code. At the moment, you don't necessarily have a dependency on the `UserModule`, just on _a_ module that provides the `UserService` token provider.

Comment: Alright, I consider this as Nestjs design flaw and accept your solution as the best possible.